# jquery Sortable ui save tr position

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-sortable

how do I preserve the position of my elements after a save to the database? Meaning, let's say I have a table inside which I have textboxes inside tds, and I rearrange the rows in my table and click Submit. How do I preserve the new posisition of the rows in my table without reverting back to the original position on page refresh?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your database, have a field called something like "sorting" or "position" and when the form is saved, serialize the data of the positions as actual positions (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3...). When the page is initially loaded, in your query, order the results by position ASC, e.g. `SELECT * FROM txt ORDER BY position ASC;`

Comment: Why should I order them? If I have let's say 3 rows in my table and I rearranged them like (position 2, position 0, position 1), I want to keep this new position even if I refresh the page. I don't want to revert back to (position 0, position 1, position 2).

Comment: Okay, say you have 1 Apple, 2 Banana, 3 Orange, and you rearrange them to 2 Banana, 3 Orange, 1 Apple.  When you save, update the database so that the positions:entries are this: 1 Banana, 2 Orange, 3 Apple. That way, when you pull the entries, they'll be in the order you saved them in.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your input with the same name.

e.g.

When you post the values, just loop through their positions or just save the whole string/array.